# Why can't I remove the directory?

Tags: delete

```
debian8@hwy:~$ ls  -al  /var/www/html/wp/.git
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 debian8  debian8  4096 Jan  2 14:07 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 www-data www-data 4096 Jan  2 06:43 ..
```

`/var/www/html/wp/.git` belong to debian8, why can't it be removed by debian8?

```
debian8@hwy:~$ rm  -rf  /var/www/html/wp/.git
rm: cannot remove ‘/var/www/html/wp/.git’: Permission denied
```

`sudo rm  -rf  /var/www/html/wp/.git` can work, why not `rm  -rf  /var/www/html/wp/.git`?

The parent directory of `/var/www/html/wp/.git` is `/var/www/html/wp` which does not belong to debian8, but I don't think it matters.

Comment: Probably because the parent directory is not owned by you.  Do not delete the parent directory.  Run the same command but with `sudo` in front of it.  `sudo rm -rf /var/www/html/wp/.git`

Comment: Does  `rm -rf /var/www/html/wp/.git` delete the parent directory `/var/www/html/wp/`?

Comment: No it does not.

Comment: To answer that question, it needs the sudo because without it, it cannot update the parent folder about the contents being removed from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The parent directory of `/var/www/html/wp/.git` is `/var/www/html/wp`
>   which does not belong to debian8, but I don't think it matters.

It does. You need write permissions on a directory to delete (or move, rename, etc.) stuff in it. Since `debian8` doesn't own `/var/www/html/wp`, and only the owner has write permissions to that directory, only root or the owner can delete files or directories from `/var/www/html/wp`.

Answer (score 2):

Run the `rm` command with with root privileges `sudo rm  -rf  /var/www/html/wp/.git`